# use click events in cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a list of items displayed by a cursor adapter, when I use `onItemClick`, I get the correct row and am able to do what i need (my objective is to add a view to that item on click.
now I need this action t happen while clicking a button in the `listView` cell.
however, button click events do not return the correct cell, but rather random other cells in the list, here is an example from my code:

```
public class CustumAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements OnClickListener{
    
    private Context context;
    
    private Button btn_maybe;

    private String name;

    public CustumAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, LatLng position) {
        super(context, c);
        
        this.position = position;
        this.context = context;
        
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor c) {
    
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContractPlaces.PLACE_NAME));
        btn_maybe = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cursor_layout_maybe);
        btn_maybe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                //i need to use the correct view from BindView here
                
            }
        });
        
        
        
        nameView.setText(name);
```

In this sample code I want a click on an button in the cell let me accesses the view in which the button really is, however I get back views from random list cells, how can I get the correct cell info in my click listener?

EDIT:

so thanks to @darnmason I figured it out, in order to get a view for a list item using a click event in cursor adapter, set the button in question a tag which will be cursor.getPosition(), so the tag is the correct position of the item, in true essence of the listview life cycle, if I want the View of an item in a specific position I will call

```
  //where lv is the ListView (you can pass it to the adapter as a parameter).
//getChildAt returns a view in a position
//value is the value of cursor.getPosition() so its the correct position of the item where //the button was clicked.
//lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() is the first position that is actually on screen,
    View view = lv.getChildAt(value - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

when you deduct this from the actual position you get the position you need, don't forget to add

```
 if(view == null)
               return;
```

to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is declared in the class and overwritten every time `bindView` is executed, when you click on the button the most recently bound view is shown in the `Toast`.

A pattern I like to follow is to store the index of the clickable view in its tag. Then in onClick you get the index from the view, and get the data for that index from the adapter.

Comment: my problem is the in onClickListener i only get the view of the button and i need the view of the whole cell like in bindView

Comment: I mean set the tag on the button in bindView, so in onClick you get the index from the tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTag` and `getTag`

```
btn_maybe.setTag(name);
```

Then in `onClick`

```
String value = (String) v.getTag();
```

Use the value to display the toast

```
Toast.makeText(context, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: im sorry i was not more specific but the String "name" was just an example, i actually need the view.

Comment: @ZivKesten what view are you talking about.

Comment: the view of the cell i am working on at the time, the view from the bindView

Comment: @ZivKesten use the same method you can set tag and get tag instead of name it will be the view

Comment: i tried but in onClickLIstener i get the view for the button not the view for the cell and that is the one i need to work with

Comment: tried it in the same toast, got the correct info from the button view, and random info from the view i tagged from bind view, can you post some example code on how to use this button to change somthing in the view please? thank for all the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55150/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-ziv-kesten).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class that does implements onClickListener and provide the object to 
the constructor:

```
private static MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        Context mContext;
        String mName;
        public MyOnClickListener(Context context, String name) {
           mContext = context; 
           mName = name;
         }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, mName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor c) {

   name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContractPlaces.PLACE_NAME));
   btn_maybe = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cursor_layout_maybe);
   btn_maybe.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(context, name));
```